# Lista de shortcuts do Eclipse EE

Tags: eclipse

Eu procurei na [documentação oficial](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-keybindings.htm) e não encontrei. Lá só tem do Eclipse SDK.

É possível exportar um PDF ou lista de **TODOS** atalhos do Eclipse EE Luna?

Answer (score 1):

`Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Keys` > `Export CSV`

Answer (score 1):

No próprio Eclipse, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> lista todos os atalhos de teclado.

Comment: A questão é que eu queria imprimir

Comment: É só fazer um *print-screen*, ou uma série e photoshopar, @Bruno